# How can I assign a user's message into a variable in discord.py?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

I want to know how I can a assign a user's message into a variable in discord.py, as I am making a Discord bot for covid19, so i want to assign the user's country name to a variable in Discord.

Comment: You might want to elaborate more so that someone can help you. If you have some code you should include it in your question.

Comment: i havent wrote a code yet, just asking before i make, i want to take input from user(in python we use x = input(".......")) , but how to do the same in discord?

Comment: You can take input from a user in discord.py using [`Client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)

Comment: The word beside ctx between the parentheses is called an argument. It is commonly used for input in discord.py

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways you can do this, you can either pass the `country` as a parameter when executing the command or you can use [`client.wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for) to wait for a user to enter their country.

Method 1 (Using `country` parameter) :

```
@client.command()
async def country(ctx,country):
    await ctx.send(f"Country chosen: {country}")
```

Method 2 (Using [`client.wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for) function) :

```
@client.command()
async def country(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Enter your country below.")
    country = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
    country = country.content;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a MySQL database and assign all info to the table or you can use a list and append to it.
Sample Code For an Easy List Append:

```
user_country = []

@client.command()
global user_country
async def country (ctx, country):
     member = ctx.author
     user_country.append(country)
     await ctx.send(f"This is where {member.mention} lives. {country} Your info has been 
     updated")
```